# What permissions for using only Sharepoint SOAP Calls to read/write to a list and upload attachments?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, sharepoint-permissions

I'm developing a web form, that writes data to a SharePoint online list using [this library](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API), reads the entry and uploads attachments. Right now, for testing, I use the login data to my Office 365 account, with access to all other MS Services.

What I need is a user account, that only has read/write permission to selected lists and nothing else.

Is that the right approach? What do I have to look for? (Sorry I'm new to SharePoint/Office365 and I have to do it together with the admin, and I like to know what they have to look for, if that makes sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using SOAP. Those APIs are ancient and probably deprecated in Microsoft 365. You should use the Microsoft Graph API for creating integrations [Microsoft Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api). If you are looking at scripting, you can use the PnP libraries. [Microsoft PnP](https://aka.ms/m365pnp)

If you need to build a web form in Microsoft 365 you should look at using Microsoft Forms, it'll do most everything you need for basic input, upload, and SharePoint integration (you may need Flow/Power Automate).

Comment: Thanks for your point of view. I'll look into using Microsoft Forms, I think that might be the best option to put all the responsibility onto MS :). I'll also check out their REST API.

Comment: Looks like MS Forms doesn't allow file upload in public forms, only within the organization. But I'm looking at https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO that uses the JSON REST API and allows authentication with "app principals (client credentials)" which seems to be better than using username:password.

Comment: That makes sense. Good luck and welcome to the community.